# How do I write a comment for an item I defined in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, asdoc

I want to add a comment to some elements in a Flex document, and process the comments using ASDoc. I can easily do this for the script portion, but I end up with a ton of ugly "This property can be used as the source for data binding." messages for each element I declared in Flex.

Is there any way to embed a comment into a flex element so that it can be read by ASDoc? I have tried using the standard

```
<!-- -->
```

notation, but that didn't seem to work.

EDIT: The notation seems to be swallowed up as an HTML comment, I presume you know what it looks like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to put comments in the markup?

According to the Flex Documentation [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_3.html), "Because the format of an ASDoc comment uses ActionScript syntax, you can only insert an ASDoc comment in an  block of an MXML file."

Comment: This limitation was removed in Adobe Flex 4 and you can now create ASDocs in MXML.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your code it is a bit hard to tell exactly what is going on.  Nothing about ASdocs should be generating an bindable compiler error.  Are you getting that error from the Flex compiler or the ASDoc compiler?  Are you trying to document an MXML Document or an ActionScript document?

Have you read these docs?

On [ActionScript](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_4.html#189665):

```
/**
* Your Comment Goes Here
*/
ActionScript Element
```

And on [MXML](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/ASDoc+in+MXML)?  MXML ASDoc comments must user three dashes, not 2 for the first comment marker.  Like this:

```
<!--- Your comment goes here -->
MXML Element
```

Comment: I think the triple dash vs double dash in the start comment marker is the bit of info that the OP needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these // and /* */ (within ActionScript blocks) 
To comment out a MXML node use `<!-- and end with -->`